# What is the Best way to Load balance Azure web apps deployed under one Azure App Service plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have 1 Webapp running under same App service plan. As  I am using a premium Azure app service plan with 15 instances, We are  consuming only 10 percent of CPU. So to increase more availability and responsiveness of our app, I was planning to deploy one more instance of same app with a different name under same App service plan.

So now I am running my-app and my-app01 under 1 app service plan. Now I want to distibute the incoming traffic between this 2 apps.
As this app's are running under on app service, they are running on same location. So Azure Traffic manager doesn't allow the endpoints from same location. To by pass this I have used Traffic manager nested nedpoint to list my both app endpoints under one traffic manager.

then I have added my custom domain name to traffic manager as a CNAME record mapping.

```
myapp.abhisqs.com -> abhisq.trafficmanager.net -> (my-app.azurewebsites.net , my-app01.azurewebsites.net)
```

After doing this I am not able to open my app by hitting https://myapp.abhisqs.com/pages/default.aspx from Url, it was throwing 403 error. So I added a hostname(myapp.abhisqs.com) and SSL binding for my-app.  Then I was able to open my app by using the https://myapp.abhisqs.com/pages/default.aspx.

So Now my other app instance my-app01 doesn't have a Hostname and SSL binding, So if my primary app (my-app) is off, then I am not able to open the app UI ( fails with error 403). Also from Azure portal I am not able to add host name and SSL binding to my second app which is running under same app service plan.  It throws error "the host name 'myapp.abhisqs.com' is alredy configured for my-app so first remove that then configure with this."

So my question is what is best way to have multiple apps under same service plan, load balanced under one single custom domain name.

Comment: Are you're doing this to go over the 20 instances limit?  If so, open a support ticket and ask to get a higher limit.

Comment: our main requirement is , even if we use 20 instances, we are consuming only 20% of  CPU and 15% of memory. We can run few more instance of the same app on these VM, to optimize the resource consumption.